# looking for hexlike-bit to unscrew bottom of ikea couch leg

Tags: screws, bits

We're trying to unscrew a leg from an Ikea couch (it's possibly the Stockholm model, not sure). The bolt on the inside looks hexlike, but all the hex bits we've tried doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone tell us what bit should be used to take this screw off?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried metric and SAE and Torx size bits?

Comment: It's probably a metric size that's between SAE sizes.

Comment: Agree with Mike's but it is a hex not a torx try both metric and sae sizes or you might strip it out.+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5mm is one of the most used sizes for IKEA furniture, but 4mm and 6mm are common as well.  I doubt a nice sturdy foot on a couch would be using anything smaller.

If you have some bike tools around, try them.  They will be metric sized hex.

Comment: Thanks for everyone you replied. We had a contractor come in and just use a large flat screwdriver bit to remove the screw.

@BowlOfRed is probably right, this was probably a metric sized bit, I didn't verify that though, I didn't have any of those bits with me.